# Git: Retrieve all new and modified files between two revisions

Tags: git

I'm trying to use diff command to get all modified and new files, between 2 revisions on git using the SHA.

Right now I'm able to generate a patch using the following example command.

git diff SHA1 SHA2 > patch.txt

However, I need the entire version of new/modified files on a zip file or in a folder.

[edit, more info]
I really need an output with the entire files changed, not on a patch format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, a disclaimer; I don't know anything about Perforce.  That said, why can't you just take the patch from `git` and apply it to your perforce environment?  Something like:

```
git diff sha1 sha2 | (cd /my/perforce/repo; patch -p1)
```

This should take care of translating all the modifications into the new environment.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you can get a list of new/modified/deleted files between revisions like this:

```
$ git log --name-status --pretty=format:'%H'  sha1..sha2
```

Which will give you output like this:

```
0bf1587d08e303bc167b713eb5a9c05d55b34fde
M       fragments/kube-examples.yaml

36ba26ec88ac478eb4dc29b997c9e37fa51e37cf
M       fragments/configure-kubernetes-master.sh

6595da2f666dbe5c473457cd023c2a81555cb3b9
M       fragments/docker.service.yaml
D       fragments/wait-for-flanneld.yaml
M       kubenode.yaml

cb51ae97b769354656e103655c2532562b15c079
M       fragments/configure-flannel.sh
```

That is, for each commit id, provide a list of added, deleted, or
modified files.  You could run this through a shell script to zip up
the named files.  This won't get you exactly what you want, but maybe
it will inspire an appropriate solution?

Comment: The perfoce part I'll do manually. I really need an output with the entire files changed, not on a patch format.

Answer (score 1):

execute a git diff and pipe to patch file (as you described and then compress it to zip)

as you already mentioned in your Q: `git diff sha1..sha1 >> patches a.txt`

then you can compress it into zip: (depend on your OS or use 7-zip which is cross platform)

if you need the files execute this:

`cp -pv --parents git diff --name-only DESTINATION-DIRECTORY`

or this full bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Target directory
TARGET=/target/directory/here

for i in $(git diff --name-only)
    do
        # First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist.
        mkdir -p "$TARGET/$(dirname $i)"
        # Then copy over the file.
        cp "$i" "$TARGET/$i"
    done
```

another way can be to use **[`Patches by Email`](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/12/git-tip-of-week-patches-by-email.html)**

Comment: I really need an output with the entire files changed, not on a patch format.

Comment: Then you will need to do a diff and then process the names of the files.

Comment: Where I can specify the sha on bash script? Thanks!

Comment: you can add the sha-1 in the if condition `git diff --name-only` as regular diff command

Comment: sorry for a newbie question, I'm using cmd windows and generating bat file, I got the error "i was unexpected at this time". :S